# SQL Server / MS Access help understanding WHERE CLAUSE in terms of NULLS and LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following example generated by MS Access for generating results base on table1 without matching table2 on the IP Address columns.

```
SELECT 
    Table1.ID, Table1.IP_Address, Table1.Field1 
FROM 
    Table1 
LEFT JOIN
    Table2 ON Table1.[IP_Address] = Table2.[IP Address] 
WHERE 
    (((Table2.[IP Address]) IS NULL));
```

While trying to analyze "WHERE (((Table2.[IP Address]) Is Null))" I do not understand how this makes sense, as I interpret it as only return results that are NULL for table2@IP Address. My understanding of WHERE clause is like a filter mechanism for your query and NULL is blank. Can someone help me understand this counter-intuitive statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a more intuitive way to write the query would use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.IP_Address, Table1.Field1 
FROM Table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM Table2 
                  WHERE Table1.[IP_Address] = Table2.[IP Address]
                 );
```

That said, the `LEFT JOIN` method is perfectly reasonable -- and sensible too.

`LEFT JOIN` keeps all the rows in the first table (`Table1`) and matching rows in the second.  If there is no match, then the `Table2` columns need to be filled with a value -- and for the non-matches, that value is `NULL`.

The `WHERE` clause is keeping only these `NULL` values.  Voila!  It keeps the rows in `Table1` that have no matching value in `Table2`.

Answer (score 1):

You already mentioned the answer:

> generating results base on table1 without matching table2

You use a `LEFT JOIN`, so you get all the rows from the *LEFT* table and matching and empty (`null`) as unmatced rows from the *RIGHT* table. 
The unmatched rows from the *RIGHT* table will have `Table2.[IP Address]` equal to `Null` (since they are unmatching). 
So the condition:

```
WHERE Table2.[IP Address] Is Null
```

will do exactly what you need:

> fetch only these rows from the *LEFT* table that do not have a match
>   on the *RIGHT* table

.